# How to change background color of tabbed panel (KivyMD/Python)

Tags: python, kivymd

I have an application where I would like to put tabbed panel in the middle of a screen like in the attached screenshot.

MDTabs in the middle of the screen:

[image: MDTabs in the middle of the screen]

The reason for placing it in the middle of the screen is that a content of these tabs depends on some configuration options in the upper part of the screen.

My issue is that with the background panel (blue rectangle) it looks like completely separated from the top part of the screen (looks like a screen split into two) while it is strictly correlated.

To make it visually related I would like to remove the background of the MDTabs or set it to the background of the page. Actually this is often the case in material design spec, see https://m3.material.io/components/tabs/guidelines

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

This should work with light and dark mode (even if this would require app restart).

Minimalistic code producing the attached screenshot is:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout

kv = '''
MDScreen:
    id: scr
    FloatLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDTopAppBar:
            id: topb
            title: "Test App"
            elevation: 4
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            
        MDLabel:
            text: "Some configuration"
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.8}
            size_hint_y: 0.1

        MDTabs:
            id: tabs
            size_hint: (1, 0.5)
            Tab:
                id: tab_rounds
                title: "Tab 1"
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Content of Tab 1"
            Tab:
                id: tab_points
                title: "Tab 2"
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Content of Tab 2"
            Tab:
                id: tab_points
                title: "Tab 3"
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Content of Tab 3"
'''

class Tab(MDFloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    '''Class implementing content for a tab.'''
class TestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        #self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
TestApp().run
()
```

I tried changing `background`, `backgroud_color` and `md_bg_color`, but none of these are related to the bar with tabs, rather to the tab content.

I tried also changing `theme_cls.primary_palette` but this changes color of `MDTopAppBar` as well which I don't want to change and the list of possible colors is predefined and doesn't include black or white.